# postgres STDDEV aggregate behavior when n<2

Tags: postgresql, null, statistics, aggregate, standard-deviation

My `Postgres` query calculates statistical `aggregate` from a bunch of sensor readings:

```
SELECT to_char(ipstimestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24') As row_name, 
to_char(ipstimestamp, 'FMDD mon FMHH24h') As hour_row_name, 
varid As category, 

(AVG(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2)) ||', ' || 
(MAX(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT  ||', ' || 
(MIN(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT  ||', ' || 
(STDDEV(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT  ||', ' As StatisticsValue 

FROM loggingdb_ips_integer As log 
JOIN ipsobjects_with_parent ips ON log.varid = ips.objectid 
AND (ipstimestamp > (now()- '2 days'::interval)) 
GROUP BY row_name, hour_row_name, category;
```

This works fine as long as I have `>1 ipsvalue/hour`. If the hourly `COUNT(ipsvalue)<2`, however, `StatisticsValue` returns `NULL` without any Postgres errors.

If I comment out `STTDEV`, as in the following:

```
(AVG(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2)) ||', ' || 
(MAX(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT  ||', ' || 
(MIN(ipsvalue)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT  ||', ' As value
```

then all three stats are calculated correctly. I therefore conclude that an illegittimate `STDDEV` brings down the whole query. I would rather have illegittimate STDDEVs returning 0. I tried to `COALESCE` the `STDDEV` line, to no avail. What can be done???

Comment: How did you use `coalesce`? This should work: `(coalesce(STDDEV(ipsvalue), 0)::NUMERIC(5,2))::TEXT`

Comment: Clodoaldo, many thanks!!! I have tried your syntax, and indeed it works as expected! Apparently I had messed up the COALESCE syntax, I had too many colons and too many transforms from number to text and back!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COALESCE` should work.

You could also use (it that fits you) the "[population standard deviatio](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE)n" `stddev_pop`, instead of the "sample standard deviation" `stddev_samp`; the later is  divides by `n-1` and is aliased to `STDDEV`.  `stddev_pop`, instead , divides by `n` , and it returns zero (instead of `NULL`) when given one sample.

If you don't know the difference between these estimators, it's explained in every statistic textbook, eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation

Comment: Leonbloy, many thanks indeed for your help. Your explanations are very clear and helpful. I appreciate your taking the time to guide me through this! I eventually managed to get COALESCE to work (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which is an alternative to COALESCE. In my specific instance, COALESCE is likely to perform better, but the workaround is potentially more flexible.

I have taken advantage of the IIF [simulation described by Emanuel Calvo Franco and Hector de los Santos](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Simulating_iif_function). IIF works pretty much like its homologue in MS Access. In my instance, the IIF function tests the result of STDDEV for NULL, and returns a "0" if true. The good thing about IIF is that it can test all sorts of conditions, not only NULL.